# trying to split a string on the space after a floatingpoint number - python positive lookbehind assertion

Tags: python, regex

```
entry = '1.1 Ensure that all positions have current ...'

print regex.split(' (?<=[0-9]*\.*[0-9])',entry)

result = [u'1.1 Ensure that all positions have current ...']
```

Which I suppose means there is no result. (PS the ellipsis isn't in the string)
The number is not a float but a list number so I don't need to find `+-eE` etc they will never show up

I want the out put to be

```
[u'1.1', u'Ensure that all positions have current ...']
```

I'm using, Python 2.7 and the regex module which allows variable length positive look behinds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a straight split:

```
>>> entry = '1.1 Ensure that all positions have current'
>>> entry.split(' ',1)
['1.1', 'Ensure that all positions have current']
```

Or, if you want a regular expression:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\d+\.?\d+)', entry)
['', '1.1', ' Ensure that all positions have current']
```

From the [`re.split` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the
>   start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The
>   same holds for the end of the string

Comment: yes - simple. I was so caught up using regex for other things I forgot to use python!!! This will work because all the strings already begin with a number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use positive look ahead, since you starting from the beginning of the string and you have to remember that look arounds don't consume (zero-width-assertion).

```
re.split('(?=[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)([0-9]\.[0-9])',entry)
```

So don't forget to consume the numbers after confirming the numbers are there.